# How to get out of dependency hell

Tags: dependencies

I am doing this from memory from work.

Basically, I have libjpeg-turbo8 installed. But I have libjpeg-turbo8:i386 installed at version xxx4.4 and libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 installed at version xxx4.3. I am not sure how this mismatch happened.

I believe that 4.3 is the right version, so I would like to roll the 32 bit version back. apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8:i386xxxxxx4.3 did not work (as it was still complaining that it couldnt do anything because of the mismatch).

Basically, I cant do anything with apt-get because this mismatch is causing dependency hell. What is the proper way to resolve this.

The box is 64 bit 12.04.

Edit: sudo aptitude -f install pops the same error.

Answer (score 0):

install aptitude and do this,

```
sudo aptitude -f install
```

Then, follow the instruction.

Comment: Yeah... I forgot to say it but doing that just makes it complain about the mismatch too.